# How to apply Google Analytics (GA4) tracking code to every page in a Bubble webapp?

Tags: google-analytics, bubble.io

I am using the official GA4 plugin for Bubble.io. However there is only one tracking code field per app, while an app might consist of multiple pages. From what I understood, tracking code is to be applied to every page of the application. How do I gather data from each of the pages then? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a tracker to every page, within your app, navigate to Settings -> SEO/metatags and scroll down to Script/metatags in Header or Script in body to add your tracking snippet.